# How to disable auto-detected JPA in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-jpa

I'm building a quarkus project with 3 modules: api (jax-rs), web (vaadin) and model (shared). The model module contains entity classes annotated with JPA @Entity.

The api module can compile and use the classes sucessfully, however, the web module fails to start as it can't find the default datasource:

```
Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit, but no default datasource was found.
```

How can a web application use the shared entity class definition, for example in rest client, wihtout triggering JPA detection by Quarkus (just ignore the annotations and use it as a plain object)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want @Entity to be picked up ? don't add Hibernate/JPA extension to the project would be the easiest.

Comment: Makes total sense, thank you, probably i just need the annotations from jakarta.persistence-api

Comment: @JulioFaerman you don't even need that if you are not compiling it. Annotations does not need to be on classpath when running.